# Rails 3 -> Ahoy plugin for user activity tracking-> Installation error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, ahoy

I have installed the Gem Ahoy as per the instruction in the link ->
https://github.com/ankane/ahoy

Add this line to your application’s Gemfile:

```
gem 'ahoy_matey'
```

And add the javascript file in app/assets/javascripts/application.js after jQuery.

```
//= require jquery
//= require ahoy
```

MySQL or SQLite

Add activeuuid to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'activeuuid', '>= 0.5.0'
```

And run:

```
rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

The last command produces following error

```
rake db:migrate
==  CreateVisits: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:visits, {:id=>false})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "binary" does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "visits" ("id" binary(16) PRIMARY KEY, "visitor...
```

Comment: binary doesnt exist in sqlite

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question that has been fixed on the latest versions of Ahoy. The error message means that the MySQL database does not have a `binary` data type. To resolve this error, try these solutions.

1. Modify the data type of the `id` column from `binary` to `bytea` in Ahoy migration file:

   ```rb
   create_table :visits, id: false do |t|
     t.bytea :id, limit: 16, primary_key: true
     # Other fields
   end
   ```
2. Or run this command after `bundle install`:

   ```rb
   rails generate ahoy:install
   ```
3. Skip the `activeuuid` gem and the `rails generate ahoy:stores:active_record` command because the `activeuuid` gem is only required for PostgreSQL. Run this command to create the visits table:

   ```rb
   rails generate ahoy:stores:sql
   ```

Finally:

```rb
rails db:migrate
```